# Knockout: Asynchronous call in model binding

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asynchronous, knockout.js

I'm having a problem. My async return method is never hit. I do not get to use the response of $.getJSON and show it in the UI.
Here's the code:

```
function SearchResult() {
    var self = this;
    self.Class;
    self.Id;
    self.Type;
    self.Naam;
    self.Omschrijving;
    self.DocumentLink;

    // added to server side object model
    self.DetailUrl;

    self.detailsContent = ko.observable();
    self.detailsEnabled = ko.observable(false),
    self.enableDetails = function () {
        var aUrl = "/Search/GetDocuments?Id=" + this.Id + "&type=" + this.Type;
        $.getJSON(aUrl, function (data)
        {
            this.detailsContent(data);
            this.detailsEnabled(true);
        });
    };
    self.disableDetails = function() {
        this.detailsEnabled(false);
    }
}

<!-- knockout template search results -->
                <div class="list-group searchresults" data-bind="foreach: searchResults">

                    <div class="list-group-item" data-bind="event: { mouseover: enableDetails, mouseout: disableDetails }">
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href : DetailUrl, target : '_blank'}"><h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-bind="text: Naam"></h4></a>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">
                            <span data-bind="text: Omschrijving"></span>

                        </p>
                        <div data-bind="visible: detailsEnabled">
                            <div data-bind="html: detailsContent"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Just to be clear, this is never executed:

```
 this.detailsContent(data);
 this.detailsEnabled(true);
```

The purpose of this all is to asynchronously load a piece of html on mouseover of an element.

Comment: Check the console. Look at the network tab. Are you sure your `$.getJson` call is not returning errors?

Answer (score 3):

in the  `enableDetails` function, and the callback of the get request, `this` is not the same `this` as the one in `SearchResult`, you have to do as follows:

```
self.enableDetails = function () {
    var aUrl = "/Search/GetDocuments?Id=" + self.Id + "&type=" + self.Type;
    $.getJSON(aUrl, function (data) {
        self.detailsContent(data);
        self.detailsEnabled(true);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help taxicala. However, this isn't the solution. Both this and self give the correct values. The aUrl variable is correct and works. However, the return method of the asynchronous getJSON call is never reached, so the content isnt shown.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason getJSON does not work but $.ajax success function does work.
Working correctly asynchronously:

```
function SearchResult() {
    var self = this;
    self.Class;
    self.Id;
    self.Type;
    self.Naam;
    self.Omschrijving;
    self.DocumentLink;

    // added to server side object model
    self.DetailUrl;

    self.detailsContent = ko.observable();
    self.enableDetails = function () {
        var aUrl = "/Search/GetDocuments?Id=" + self.Id + "&type=" + self.Type;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: aUrl,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                self.detailsContent(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                window.location.href = "/Error/ShowError?message=" + encodeURIComponent("Onbekende fout bij het zoeken.");
            }
        });
    };
}
```